# Creating Data Formatted Correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sort of a re-ask of the previous question with a more specific question.

1. Here is the JSFiddle to my code: https://jsfiddle.net/frtvq0hu/1/ (Everything happens in the console).
2. This is what the incoming data looks like:

   ```
   var dataArr = [
       {id: 123, name:"Alexey Ayzin"},
       {id: 234, name:"Mira Mdivani"},
       {id: 345, name:"Maria Iliakova"},
       {id: 456, name:"Dennis Ayzin"}
   ];
   ```

   3.My data needs to look like this:

   ```
   data = [
       {id: 123, str:"Alexey Ayzin", fG:"", bG:""},
       {id: 234, str:"Mira Mdivani", fG:"", bG:""},
       {id: 345, str:"Maria Iliakova", fG:"", bG:""},
       {id: 456, str:"Dennis Ayzin", fG:"", bG:""},
   ];
   ```

But with the fg and bg filled. How can I fill the fg and bg with generated elements and would I do so with push or another function. Thanks.

Comment: Basically "How to write a for loop in Javascript?"

Comment: Did you read my code? @meskobalazs

Comment: @maioman didn't exactly work. Unless I'm doing it wrong. Any help/other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the following code block to populate `data` just before last console.log(). Is it solve your problem?

```
for(var i =0; i < text.bg.length; i++) {
   data[i].fG = text.fg[i];
   data[i].bG = text.bg[i];
}

console.log(data);
```

Comment: That's actually pretty close to what i did. I found that I was pushing to JSON and that didn't work, so I set equal signs instead and it works perfectly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution with array.map():

```js
var dataArr = [
    {id: 123, name:"Alexey Ayzin"},
    {id: 234, name:"Mira Mdivani"},
    {id: 345, name:"Maria Iliakova"},
    {id: 456, name:"Dennis Ayzin"}
];

// {id: 123, str:"Alexey Ayzin", fG:"", bG:""},
var r = dataArr.map(function(o){
   return{
     id: o.id,
     str: o.name,
     fG: '',
     bG: ''
   }
})

console.log(r)
```